# Lattice representation of undirected graph

Tags: graph

Under what circumstances can an undirected graph be represented by 
integer lattice points in Cartesian coordinates? Specifics:

% Each point on the graph is mapped to (x,y) on the Cartesian grid 
 where both x and y are integers.

% Two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) on the Cartesian grid are 
 "connected" if abs(x1-x2)<=1 and abs(y1-y2)<=1. In other words, each 
 point has 8 neighbors.

% Two points on the Cartesian graph representation should be 
 connected iff there is an edge between those two points on the 
 graph.

Examples:

% K4: All points are connected to each other.

```
 
12 
34
```

% K2,2: 1 and 2 both connect to both 3 and 4 but there are no other 
 connections.

```
 
 3 
1 2 
 4
```

Since I can't find a lattice representation for K3,2 I'm guessing 
lattice-able graphs are a proper subset of planar graphs.

Same question for 3D lattice points.

Answer (score 0):

This lattice type graph is planar since K5 and K3,3 can't be represented. K5 since in K1,5 there is at least one pair of nodes (from 5) that are not connected. K3,3 since it is not possible to place 3 unconnected points that there 'circles' intersect on more that one point.

It is proper subset of planar graphs since K1,9 can't be represented.

For 3D case it is not planar since K5 can be represented, K4 from 2D and one point on top of them. But some planar graphs can't be represented, e.g. K1,28.